# How can you get the number of times an element appears in another column within a range?

Tags: r

I want to know how often an element from one column appears in another

Let's say I have two columns.  In these columns, I have a series of times (in milliseconds).  One column represents a gold standard (method 2) and the novel method (method 1).  I would like to create a function in which I can read any csv with 2 columns (method1 and method2) and I want it to count the frequency that the times from method1 appear in method 2.  Furthermore, because we are dealing with milliseconds, I would like to have a very small degree of tolerance i.e. if its 0.005 milliseconds, I want it to count +/- 0.002 as well (so it counts from 0.003 to 0.007).

My end point is to output a csv that adds a 3rd column that shows the frequency of times from method1 appearing in method2.

I have tried the following code:

```r
df<-read.csv("/Users/user/Desktop/R_workingdir/test__test.csv")

method1<-df$method1
method2<-df$method2

method1<-toString(method1)
method2<-toString(method2)

summarise(group_by(df,method1,method2),count =n())
```

...But it only counts the frequency in the same column:

[image: Please find attached the image of the expected input, output and what I am currently getting]

PS. I am new to RStudio so it would be great if you can provide a short explanation of the code so I could understand.

Comment: the columns are numeric floats.  So, there is a chance that the digit precision is not matching.  May be you need to round the columns or convert to character and then doo the `count`

Comment: Could you post your code in your question please?

Comment: Done.  Sorry about that

Comment: Please use actual text rather than screenshots. This is hard to read and not copy-paste friendly.

Answer (score 1):

```
df = read.delim("./temp.tsv") #you seem to have a tab separated file, at least according to your screen shot
tolerance = 0.002 #set the tolerance
counts = sapply(
  df$Method2,
  #input values for the comparisons (this will substitute the 'x' in the function below)
  FUN = function(x) {
    #we define a comparison function on the fly
    sum(df$Method1 >= x - tolerance &
          df$Method1 <= x + tolerance) #sum the times a value is true, i.e. falls into the specified range
  }
)

output_df = cbind(df, counts) #that just binds the columns together into one data frame
```

write.csv(output_df, "output.csv") #beware that this writes true csv and not tab-delimited files as your input seems to be

I'm not sure if your input is actually numbers, or the numbers with dots after. For the 3rd value of Method 2 this (should) give Count = 0, since there is no value between 0.012 and 0.016 in Method 1

Comment: If you need help with formatting of the input, please post it in a copy-able form